# Windows Debugger Road-Map

Tags: windows, debugging, crash-dumps

It seems there are dozens of debugger and debugging tools that Microsoft produces, which creates a maze of choices and questions concerning which tool to apply, and when.  For example, there is windbg - and the debugger built into Visual Studio.  Both can access minidumps.  Why would I choose one over the other?

Dr. Watson was the default post-mortem crash analysis tool of the past.  It has now been replaced with "Problem Reports & Solutions".  Which is in turn replaced with IIS Exception Monitor on servers?  And perhaps all of this is built on top of "Microsoft CDB Debugger," or perhaps that is a another duplicate tool?  ADPlus, yet another one, is built on CDB Debugger.  The maze seems to go on endlessly.

Can someone provide a link to a taxonomy or roadmap of all these tools, with comments of which are being deprecated (Dr. Watson?) and what "tool direction" debug students should absorb?  I'm sure there are a number of tools and base libraries I've not mentioned here.  it would be nice to know the dependencies between them too (such as ADPlus using the CDB Debugger).

I've found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/cdbntsd.aspx) to be helpful, since it answers some of the questions I'm asking - though the material is dated.  Any other resources that give a similarly simple compare / contrast run-down?

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between [CDB and NTSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), other than how they spawn new windows.  Choosing when to use Visual Studio over the command line debuggers is sometimes a matter of personal choice, but sometimes the command line is a better tool for the job.  Once you get good at using the command line debuggers, you can get things done much more quickly.  I suspect there are a few scenarios that remain where you can only debug a specific problem with the command line debugger, but I can't think of any off hand.  The third debugger you've missed is kd, which is the kernal debugger.  If you want to debug kernal mode stuff (i.e. your device drivers you've written) it's really your only choice.

CDB, NTSD and KD are all part of the [debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), itself part of the DDK.  Visual Studio does not depend on the other debugging package and vice-versa.

Watson and the like are not debuggers.  They merely observe and report.  I suspect the best advice there is use whichever one is appropriate to your problem.  I mean, there are lots of tools for all sorts of different MS technologies.  E.g. [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSI databases.  All of these products are unrelated, often released and maintained by different divisions, etc.  As a result, I doubt you'll find a chart showing their relationships since they are so diverse.